# Let $A$ be a vector subspace of the normed space $E$. Let $x \in E, y \in A$ and $c >0$. Show that $d(y+cx,A) =cd(x,F).$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

> Let $A$ be a vector subspace of the normed space $E$. Let $x \in E, y \in A$ and $c >0$. Show that $d(y+cx,A) =cd(x,A).$

I'm very confused with the notation here. The distance function takes in points of a space/set as an input, how can they pass the whole set there? Are they looking at the distance of a point from the whole set or what is happening here?

Comment: $d(x,A):=\inf_{y\in A}d(x,y)$.

Comment: So in essence I want to show that $d(y+cx,A)= c(\inf_{y\in A} d(x,y))$

Comment: Yes, that's correct, and if you think more about it, you'll see that it is kind of obvious.

Comment: $y+cx$ is just a line so the equality tells me that the distance of this line is some multiple away from the set $A$?

Comment: Why is $y+cx$ a line? Everything in that expression is fixed, right? The key point is $y\in A$.

Comment: As Henno pointed out the metric from norm is translation invariant so I would have that $d(y+cx, A) = c(\inf_{y\in A}d(x,y)) = \inf_{y\in A}d(cx,cy)$?

Answer (score 0):

First of all $d(x,A) = \inf \{d(x,y)\mid y \in A\}$

We can also use that a metric from a norm is translation invariant: $d(x+z,y+z)= d(x,y)$ for all $x,y,z$, and also $|c|d(x,y)=d(cx,cy)$ for all scalars $c$. Both are obvious from $d(x,y)=\|x-y\|$ and properties of the addition and the norm.